# Adding Layered Navigation Module to my theme so I can edit

Tags: magento-2.1, module, theme, layered-navigation

I need to override the default vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/view/frontend/templates/layer/view.phtml.  I am attempting to add the proper file structure to my theme but cannot get it to pick up the files in my theme.
I am using **Magento_Layered-Navigation** as the directory name and have tried a couple variations of it, but cannot get the correct naming convention.
Caching is off and i have been reloading my browser with empty cache and hard-reload ever time.
Any suggestions on what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be a simple solution.  The directory naming structure just needed to be **Magento_LayeredNavigation**.  Files are now being picked up.

Comment: Just came across this question but yes, replace all hypens (-) with camel case when copying over for the Vendor_ModuleName convention.